# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples, concatenation

I am trying to run the code optimize.py (part of the scipy pack), and it gives me this error:

*TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple*

The part of the code that is producing the error is pasted below -

```
def wrap_function(function, args):
    ncalls = [0]
    if function is None:
        return ncalls, None

    def function_wrapper(*wrapper_args):
        ncalls[0] += 1
        return function(*(wrapper_args + args))

    return ncalls, function_wrapper
```

Could you please point out where they are trying to concatenate a tuple to a list, and how to fix it?

I will provide more of the code if necessary - I have almost no knowledge in posting questions here, so I have pasted only a small section where the error is occurring.

This code is being used to run the command 'keptransit' to find a transiting exoplanet.

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Answer (score 4):

You are most likely passing a list as `args` and trying to concatenate to  `wrapper_args` which is a tuple.

So cast args to a tuple or simply pass a tuple of args.

```
 wrapper_args + tuple(args)
```

The `*wrapper_args` creates a tuple of the parameters passed in so for obvious reasons `tuple() + list()` is not going to work

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with this:

```
wrapper_args + args
```

I assume that `wrapper_args` is a tuple and `args` is a list. So for example:

```
wrapper_args = (1,2,3)
arg = [1,2,3]

wrapper_args + arg # TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list
```

Solution:

```
wrapper_args + tuple(arg)
```

Comment: `wrapper_args` is a tuple

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thx. I shortened the answer.